# searching social networking

Tags: social-networking, search

How can I organize a search in a social network web application? Searching is done by full name. I want to use stored procedures. Is it the best sollution? What algorithm can be used?

While registering, the user specifies his/her full name for ex: Alice Johnson Martin.
I want to search for a user using his/her fullname. In case someone is searching for Johnson Martin Alice, the user with the name Alice Johnson Martin should be found. I am using postgre sql and asp.net mvc.

Comment: Information provided is too scarce!

Answer (score 0):

> What algorithm can be used?

Graph algorithms, machine learning, heuristics etc come to my mind. Depends on what you want to achieve.